# Is putStrLn thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, thread-safety

I know that if I have multiple threads calling `putStrLn` without any kind of concurrency control that the output of the threads may be interleaved.

My question is whether `putStrLn` is thread-safe modulo this interleaved output?

I am presuming that `putStrLn` is a buffered write operation, so I'm really asking if any corruption of the output buffer can occur by having two threads call `putStrLn` at the same time.

And in general, what can be said about the thread safety of Haskell's (really GHC's) other "standard I/O" functions? In particular, for any of the buffered read operations is it possible for the same character to get returned to two different threads making the same read call at the same time?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a library whose stdout output isn't thread-safe (I'm thinking of the usual C/C++ runtimes, C#, Java, etc.) so if I had to take a guess I'd say it's OK here too. +1 good question though.

Comment: On Linux `putStrLn` and friends implemented via [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) couple for blocks of a fixed length (when with line- or block- buffering), so the question is whether `write` is thread-safe or not. POSIX requires thread-safety for `write` (1003.1-2001:2.9.1 & 2.9.7), and usually it is.

Comment: And `MVar` locks implemented with [`futex`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/futex) (when with `threaded` runtime). So @shachaf answer is correct.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it's thread-safe in the sense that you're asking about. A `Handle` is protected by an `MVar` which won't allow the buffer to become corrupted. As you pointed out, though, interleaving is a different matter.